# GeneralPath and the Composite pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite, primitive

A `GeneralPath` object contains `Shape`s and is itself a `Shape`.

Would this be an example of a class that uses the *Composite Pattern*?

I am confused by the *Composite Pattern* condition: "Clients treat a composite object as a primitive object."

Is this use of primitive different from a primitive data type (i.e. `int`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an example of that "pattern" (I hate the term "pattern" for more reasons than I can possibly get into in this post).

I presume you're reading from Horstmann. You are confused because "primitive" in that context means something different than "primitive" in the Java context you are comparing it to.

> Clients treat a composite object as a primitive object.

In the above context, "primitive" means the root object itself, i.e., in your case, a `Shape`.

> [Java] primitive data type (i.e. int)

In the above context, "primitive" refers to, of course, a Java primitive data type, e.g. `int` or `boolean`.

Same word, different context, different meanings.